# Lenovo ThinkPad X1 - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Battery not charging

Tags: lenovo, laptop, battery

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 with Ubuntu 22.04. Battery is not charging.

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0


native-path:          BAT0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 15 Jun 2023 21:34:06 CEST (13 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Output of `sudo tlp-stat -b`:

```
--- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: thinkpad
Supported features: charge thresholds, recalibration
Driver usage:
* natacpi (thinkpad_acpi) = active (charge thresholds)
* tpacpi-bat (acpi_call)  = active (recalibration)
Parameter value ranges:
* START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:  0(off)..96(default)..99
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:   1..100(default)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = (not available)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = (not available)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =     -1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Not charging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold =      0 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In short, as a last resort I opened Bios set up and **disabled the Battery**. When I restarted and plugged in the charger my battery started charging.

I don't know if this answers the query above; the Linux commands are new to me and still intimidating.

The long story is Yes, I have **Lenovo ThinkPad E15 Gen 4,dual boot OS  Windows and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** and I too had battery problem, battery at 97%, battery icon remains white and not charging. I plugged it in for a whole day and no change except it dropped to 95%. I called Lenovo support and after troubleshooting through video call I was told Lenovo ThinkPad E15 support Ubuntu 20.04 not 22.04. I should install Ubuntu 20.4 or Windows single boot.